# Button moves down the row

Tags: html, css

I got the following code. When I resize my browser window the button goes on the second row.

How can I keep the button on the same line?

**index.html**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
...
              <section>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills text-center">
                      <li><a href>Description</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href>Specifications</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href>Reviews</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <button ng-show="product.canPurchase" class="btn btn-primary pull-right buy-btn">Add to Cart</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
  ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

**custom.css**

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
   .buy-btn { width: 100%; display:block; }
}
```

**before resizing**

[image]

**after resizing**

[image]

**and this is what I have on the minimum window width(fully collapsed)**

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using `<div class="col-sm-9">` and `<div class="col-sm-3">`

this means that when the screen width is less than 768px it will break to col-12's

instead use `<div class="col-xs-9">` and `<div class="col-xs-3">`

Comment: Thanks, but in this case when the window's collapsed the button doesn't take the full width like on the last screenshot.

Comment: well it likely IS taking the full width, but as a col-3 it's only 25% of the row